# Cant see all of my buttons on a phone

Tags: java, android, layout

**I am making some app and cant see a button that I have created (this is when running the app on my phone) ,but if I run it on the emulator I can see everything - the button that I can't see on my phone is the clicked button (its id is "startBtn").
**

```
Here is my layout : 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:background="#798"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="unleashed.myprefs.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:text="hello"
        android:background="#ff14"
         />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/startBtn"
        android:text="start"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="addOne"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/resetBtn"
        android:text="restart"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="restart"
   />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is my main activity

```
package unleashed.myprefs;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button restartNums;
    SharedPreferences prefs;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        prefs = getSharedPreferences("main", MODE_PRIVATE);
    }
        private int getNum(){
        return prefs.getInt("num",1);
    }

    private void setNum(int num){   // put the number into my shared preference
        prefs.edit().putInt("num", num).apply();
    }

    public void addOne(View v) {    //adding number to the starting button
        int num = getNum();
        ((Button)v).setText("Clicked " + num);
        setNum(num + 1);
    }




    public void restart(View v){
        restartNums = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startBtn);
        prefs.edit().remove("num").apply();
        restartNums.callOnClick(); 
    }
    }
```

I will appreciate any help.

Comment: use this attribute on restartbtn   **android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"**

Comment: Try changing height of text view to wrap_content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. AlignParentEnd should be used in ResetButton.( Not sure )
2. (Alternative) If you trying to have two buttons in the same row, you can try this layout.. 
   `

   ```
   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/textView"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="90dp"
       android:text="hello"
       android:background="#ff14"
        />
    <LinearLayout 
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation = "horizontal"
       android:weightsum="2"
       android:layout_below="@+id/textView">

   <Button
       android:id="@+id/startBtn"
       android:text="start"
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:onClick="addOne"
       />

   <Button
       android:id="@+id/resetBtn"
       android:text="restart"
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:onClick="restart"/>
   ```

   `

Comment: thank you , linearlayout realy solved it for me , my problem was that my phone was on hebrew apparently when the whole system is changed from RTL/LTR it affect the layouts.

Comment: @TamirAbutbul Glad it helped.